# UISplitViewController on tvOS - compact mode

Tags: swift, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller, tvos, apple-tv

I'm trying to create a UIKit tvOS application using a [UISplitViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisplitviewcontroller) - ideally I would to have the primary pane overlay the child (details) and would like it to collapse to a [compact](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisplitviewcontroller/column/compact) mode when the child vc is focused. I've tried following some examples (mostly they are iOS ones) but none of them seem to use a compact mode for tvOS. Is this supported? I've tried calling something like the following in my primary vc menu:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    if let vc = self.splitViewController?.viewControllers[1] {

        vc.setNeedsFocusUpdate()
        vc.updateFocusIfNeeded()
        
        splitViewController?.show(.compact)
    }
}
```

But this always results in the exception:

'Progammatic column showing not supported for Compact column of UISplitViewController'

I can successfully hide it by calling splitViewController?.hide(.primary) but that's not really what I would like